# how to read string in sound with python without create mp3 file just with command line

Tags: python, audio, gtts

I want to make python read string which added in a variable from before because I am creating scraping script and if there are any errors, I want it to tell me, I watched many of video about that but all were about read the text and then creating mp3 file, not to read the string in the same time

Answer (score 1):

**You can use [`win32com`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartClientCom.html) to read text directly from the command line:**

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

speaker = Dispatch("SAPI.spVoice")

text = "Error" # Choose what the speaker should speak

speaker.Speak(text) # It starts speaking here
```

Answer (score -1):

i found a selution

```
import playsound
from gtts import gTTS
def speak(text):
    tts= gTTS(text= text, lang="en")
   # filename="voice.mp3"
    tts.save(filename)
    playsound.playsound(filename)
speak("error")
```